# Converting points to raster and back again in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, convert, point, raster-conversion

To convert raster grids to vector points In QGIS there we have different possibilities (grass tool "to.vect"; saga tools "grid values to points").

My problem is a little bit complicated. In the beginning I have a point layer. For further data processing I need to convert the vector points to a raster file (every point is a raster now). In the end I want to convert this raster (raster points) backwards to a point layer for the kriging tool.

The grass tool (to.vect) is very slow and the saga tools (grid values to points) gives me more than just the points I need to have (I get a very high density point shape). Is there another solution just to convert the few rasters into a point layer?

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you want the same points in the output that you had in the original input point layer? If not, which points do you want?

Comment: Yes I just want to convert the "raster points"  which I had in my original point layer.

Comment: In that case, I think you should use the original points to sample your raster layer. This will add the raster values to the original point geometries.

Comment: Which tool do I have to use for that?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/extract-raster-values-at-points