# Extracting raster values at points for GRASS GIS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, point, open-source-gis

I have points shapefile and a raster file. For each point, I want to extract the raster value which overlaps that particular point. This has been done in QGIS (link below) but I was looking for a solution for GRASS GIS.

[Extracting raster values at points using Open Source GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/extracting-raster-values-at-points-using-open-source-gis#)

EDIT: I found the blog below to be useful and posted the solution to the question below

Comment: What GRASS documentation have you studied so far? Did you find anything useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GRASS documentation](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/v.what.rast.html) on `v.what.rast` is very clear and concise. Have you tried:

```
v.what.rast map=pnts raster=elevation column=height
```

Where `pnts` is  your vector point layer; `elevation` is your raster and `height` is the attribute that will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. I found a useful blog for the solution.

https://pvanb.wordpress.com/2010/05/05/upload-raster-values-to-vector-points-using-grass-gis/