# Selecting Features in Visible Viewshed Areas using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, viewshed, visibility, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.2 I have a viewshed raster and a shapefile with point features

I'd like to select the points that intersect the visible areas of my viewshed.

Is there a way to extract a vector of my visible areas so that I can then Select by Location?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to extract the pixel value at each point and then perform a select expression to identify points in viewshed, see q/a link below:

[Extracting raster values at points using Open Source GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/extracting-raster-values-at-points-using-open-source-gis)

Another option would be to convert raster to polygon using the Polygonize tool and perform select by location:

[image]

Comment: Right, but that gives you a vector of the visible & non-visible areas of the viewshed. I ended up doing this and then my next step was to manually select the 'visible' features of that vector to create a new 'visible only' layer. (Currently Select by Location is processing). Is that really the way to do it or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Added another option to the answer.