# Extract soil and slope data using coordinates

Tags: qgis, csv, slope, soil, soilgrids

I have no experience at all in GIS and I'm trying to extract soil type and slope data. 
All I have is a CSV file with latitude and longitude coordinates.

Is it possible to use this to extract the soil type and slope data of each point?

I am using QGIS although I barely know anything.

Comment: If you have soil types and slopes for the area covered by your CSV-data, yes.

Comment: What GIS software are you using? Add a tag

Comment: @BERA I'm using QGIS

Comment: @Erik the CSV doesn't have that data. I'm trying to include it

Comment: Add the csv using "Add delimited text layer" (you might then need to save it by right-clicking the layer) then [Extracting raster values at points using Open Source GIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3538/extracting-raster-values-at-points-using-open-source-gis/3545)

Comment: Do you have a map of soil types, and if so is it in vector or raster format. You will need one or other to do the assignment of soil type to each point. Similarly, do you have something like a DEM/DTM (digital terrain model) from which to extract the slope at each point. If you have then someone here will be able to help you. If these are not available then I don't think you can proceed.

Comment: soil type is a very broad term are, you searching to a soil class, or soil property, you can check here for datasets https://www.isric.org/explore/soil-geographic-databases
also here https://data.isric.org after you can download the data (or use webservices) and to the query on QGIS